# Autofac register generic failed

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework-6, autofac, generic-programming

I have the following problem trying to configure Autofac DI container. I have generic repository  which implements interface

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity:Entity
```

UnitOfWork implementing interface

```
public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    void Dispose();
    void Save();
    void Dispose(bool disposing);
    IRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : Entity;
}
```

I am trying to inject a CRUD service implementing `ICrudService` to each of my controllers

```
public class CrudService<VM, TEntity> : ICrudService<VM,TEntity> 
        where TEntity : Entity where VM : DTOBase, new()
{
    private IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private IExtension<Entity, DTOBase> _mapper;

    public CrudService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
}
```

I tried different things in configuration of my Autofac container to make it work but nothing was successful

```
builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(Infrastructure.Repository.Repository<>)).As(typeof(Infrastructure.Repository.IRepository<>));
builder
    .RegisterType(typeof(Infrastructure.Repository.UnitOfWork))
      .As(typeof(Infrastructure.Repository.IUnitOfWork))
      .InstancePerDependency();

builder
    .RegisterGeneric(typeof(CrudService<,>)).As(typeof(ICrudService<,>)).InstancePerDependency();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
       .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(ICrudService<,>)).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I would appreciate any help

Comment: what is the error message that you get?